# Why does the API getTeamsTeamActivityDetail has missing data?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API's getTeamsTeamActivityDetail endpoint to track teams activities.

However, I am encountering an issue where the API consistently returns 1011 records active and inactive teams regardless of the period specified (D7, D30, D90, or D180), even though I am certain there are 1238 teams in our organization.

I have checked the API documentation and verified that all teams are active and should have activity that should be captured by the API. Is there a limitation or condition in the API that could be causing it to exclude the remaining 227 teams knowing that some of them are active, from the results?
If so, could you please provide guidance on how to adjust my query to retrieve data for all teams?n how to adjust my query to retrieve data for all teams?